# untill its worth / not invain

Tags: meaning, slang

I guys, I'm wondering to make a tattoo but I have been struggling a bit for the words to use; the first idea was "until it's worth" (abbreviated like 'till it's worth) but the meaning that I'm looking for is not like "play the game untill is worth then stop", rather "work untill all the struggle is not invain"
It has to be as short as possible, so maybe "make it worth"?
Any other slang that match the meaning?
I really like the "untill" construct but I'm afraid the meaning will be the opposite

Comment: *Untill* is not a word; *until* is. *Till* is its own word, and if you want to use a shortened form of *until* it would be *'til*.

Comment: @Jason - interestingly, 'till' came first, then 'until' _from_ 'till', and finally ''til', which is an erroneous backformation attempting the original 'till'. [Link](https://www.etymonline.com/word/until)

Comment: @marcellothearcane From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/till): "To sum up: *until* and *till* can be used freely and interchangeably, but you will probably want to avoid *’till* and use *’til* advisedly." Neither *'till* nor *'til* should be used in anything formal, and while both are somewhat accepted informally, *'til* (with an apostrophe and one *t*) is the more common spelling, while *'till* (with an apostrophe and two *t*s) opens you up to lots of people telling you you're wrong—even if you *can* try to claim that it has some kind of usage.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/600416/2085).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Till it's worth it" is what you'd put.  "Till" is a word that means "until." It's not a contraction of "until," so there's no apostrophe beforehand.  It's its own word.  Even Shakespeare used it.

> "Let me stand here till thou remember."
>
> -Romeo (*Romeo and Juliette* by William Shakespeare, Act 2, Scene 2)

Also, "invain" isn't a word.  It's "in vain."

Finally, "make it worth" is nonsense.  Don't get that tattooed on you.  You could put "Make it worth it."  You could also put "Make it worthwhile," but that doesn't seem very tattoo-y.

Comment: 'Until' comes from 'till', fyi - https://www.etymonline.com/word/until